# Restarting network over ssh causes hang

Tags: networking, ssh

I'm running this:

```
ssh root@192.168.88.88 '/etc/init.d/networking restart'
```

It works and outputs the results, but never returns. Yet other commands do. Maybe because the network goes down (as intended). How can I terminate it? I tried adding an exit command, but no dice.

UPDATE: I noticed this does work sometimes. The problem seems to happen if the process is interrupted and the remote interface configuration is in an unknown state. I still can't track down exactly what causes the hanging.

Comment: try `ssh ... '/etc/init.d/networking restart & exit'`... does it work? Otherwise you can kill it from another terminal (brute force approach).

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately (neither does `; exit`). I need this to be automated as part of a bigger script, so killing isn't really an ideal option.

Comment: Last try... `'(sleep 10 && /etc/init.d/networking restart ) &; exit' ;-)

Comment: Didn't work either. I also tried timeout and timelimit, but it still just hangs.

Comment: Other than my solution, try ssh ... 'nohup service networking restart &'. Nohup usually helps in these cases. I still prefer the one I put as an answer.

Comment: nohup doesn't work either unfortunately.

Comment: Probably not worth mentioning it, but in my last suggestion the `;` after `&` was a mistake.

Comment: Try if this helps ... http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/063

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the restart command is getting interrupted when the connecton is lost (at first glance asking a system to restart its network connection *over the network* seems dangerous). What you'd want is for `networking restart` to run independently of the controlling terminal. I'd add a crontab entry like so (put it in `/etc/cron.d/checker-thingy` perhaps):

```
* * * * * root /path/to/checker-thingy.sh
```

then checker-thingy.sh would be something like:

```
[ -f /tmp/restart-network ] && service networking restart
[ -f /tmp/restart-network ] && rm /tmp/restart-network
```

This is kinda awful and prone to other problems, but basically as you see it will restart the network if it finds a specific flag file in `/tmp` (and then remove the file to avoid a network resetting loop).

Then in your automated script you can do:

```
ssh server-ip 'touch /tmp/restart-network'
```

and after a minute or so you should see the network interface cycle as requested.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this very interesting page: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/063. The `ssh` command is hanging around waiting for the output streams of the remote process to close, so it will be catched by the network shutting down.

So (tested):

```
ssh user@host "sleep 60 &"
```

will return after 60 seconds, while

```
ssh user@host  "sleep 60 >/dev/null 2>&1 &"
```

will return immediately after launching the `sleep` command in background.

If this is correct, the solution would be to detach immediately the standard output and error from the remote shell --- like this (not tested, please check):

```
ssh user@host '/etc/init.d/networking restart >/dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

or if this still triggers a race between the network going down and the shell closing,

```
ssh user@host '(sleep 10 && /etc/init.d/networking restart ) >/dev/null 2>&1 &'
```

should work.

Answer (score -3):

Remove the shh package by typing

- sudo apt-get remove ssh

and reinstalling it by:

- sudo apt-get install ssh.

Comment: What would that achieve?

Comment: This is not a solution. It will achieve nothing.